# Apache - .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

As I did not find any answer that helped me out and almost going nuts here... help would be highly appreciated.

Here's the problem: I've a relaunched a website and want to redirect old and unvalid /cgi-bin/... sites to the new index. Here's what I got in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ #(this works)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] #(this works)
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin(.*)$ / [R=301,L] #(this doesn't work!)
RewriteRule ^pdf(.*)$ / [R=301,L] #(this works)
```

So my problem is this line:

```
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

If I add the exact same rule to the htaccess of a test-server (same host provider) this perfectly works. Only difference is that a cgi-bin folder exists outside of htdocs, but I think that should not be the problem. I can't see what's wrong here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when `cgi-bin` exists outside `htdocs`, the `htdocs` `.htaccess` file never runs, as it only applies to the directory that contains it and its subdirectories. Put the `cgi-bin` `RewriteRule` in a `.htaccess` file in your `cgi-bin`.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but it doesn't work either... Whether I get "foribidden" when I call /cgi-bin or "not found" when I call /cgi-bin/something-else

Comment: Do you have a `<Directory>` block set up for your cgi-bin directory, with `AllowOverride all` set? Otherwise the .htaccess file will not be processed. You may also need `Options +FollowSymlinks`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot do that as I don't have access to the httpd.conf - it's at a hosting provider. Maybe I can ask there...

Comment: Yes you'll never be able to do anything with the cgi-bin from your document root .htaccess file, since it never gets examined for those requests, so best to contact the host as you say.